# Converting list of strings to list of ints in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a line like "fun,arg1,arg2" <- it is a string

I split this string into list of strings by "," separator. Then I compare "fun" with some string (e.g. "Fibonacci").

Function for splitting (works fine)

```
(defun split-str (string &optional (r nil))
  (let ((n (position "," string
                     :from-end t
                     :test #'(lambda (x y)
                               (find y x :test #'string=)))))
    (if n
        (split-str (subseq string 0 n)
                   (cons (subseq string (1+ n)) r))
        (cons string r))))
```

Test function

```
(defun tmp (a)
  (if (string= (nth 0 a) "Fibonacci")
    (progn
      (setf tab '())
      (dolist (n (cdr a))
        (cons tab '(parse-integer n))) ; parsing works fine (checked with write)
      (write tab)) ; always NIL
            ;(apply #'parse-integer (apply #'values a)) - doesn't work

    (write "nok")))
```

Calling:

```
(tmp (split-str "Fibonacci,15,33"))
```

Why my tab hasn't 2 elements?

Comment: Please show the output trace that includes your correct split, and shows what you *do* get in the tab.  Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and other introductory help documentation for guidelines.

Comment: Please [format your code appropriately](https://google.github.io/styleguide/lispguide.xml#Formatting).

Comment: Open your REPL and enter `(setf tab '())`, `(cons tab 2)`, `tab`. Think about the results for a few minutes. Then read the introduction to lists in your fine book.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cons` doesn't change anything; it returns a new list using `tab`.

Comment: Now I see it. Could you please tell me how to modify a list (insert new element)?

Comment: @kzz you could use `(push tab (parse-integer n))`.

Comment: @kzz Or `(setf tab (cons (parse-integer n) tab))` (note that both the `cons`- and `push`-based methods would end up with `tab` having the last-seen element first, so you may want to have a `(setf tab (reverse tab))` somewhere).

Comment: @PuercoPop: `(push (parse-integer n) tab)`.